# Yup validation disable Submit till validation passes

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I have a Yup validation schema used in my React app with a couple of fields having mandatory and regex checks.

Is it possible to disable Submit button of the form till the Yup validation schema passes like a boolean value or something ?

Also, just to add, I am using React Hook Form as the underlying library and have the mode as 'onBlur'

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution -

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import * as yup from 'yup';

const schema = yup.object().shape({
  // Define your Yup validation schema here
  // Example:
  firstName: yup.string().required('First name is required'),
  lastName: yup.string().required('Last name is required'),
  // ... other fields and validation rules
});

function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors, isValid } } = useForm({
    mode: 'onBlur',
    validationSchema: schema,
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    // Handle form submission
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input {...register('firstName')} />
      {errors.firstName && <p>{errors.firstName.message}</p>}

      <input {...register('lastName')} />
      {errors.lastName && <p>{errors.lastName.message}</p>}

      {/* Add more input fields and corresponding error messages */}

      <button type="submit" disabled={!isValid}>
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default App;
```